Coauthorship of a paper with big name prof
I am 3th year PhD student. I have written 4 math-stats papers (good Q1-Q2 journals but not the top top), one alone three with my supervisor as a coauthor. I am finishing my next paper: my best idea and best work, in my humble opinion deserving to be considered in the best of the best journal. The problem with my previous papers is that although 2 of them so far were accepted to a journal, they have no citations so far (I know that takes a while, but other peers have already more citations etc and it bothers me a bit).
I am going to Berkeley for a research visit for half a year under a big name prof. Now, I can choose - either I submit the paper as a single author, or I can also ask the new prof  (maybe he will have some more ideas though and maybe will help) and include him as a coauthor.
What would you recommend doing? Some pros and cons? For a good journal acceptance, big name is always a good thing to have, and the paper can be much more cited. However, it will diminish a bit my contribution.
Edit: many answers deal with the ethical implications of including a person on a paper that did not do any work. I am not saying that I come to the prof and say 'be on the paper please'. I am trying to improve the paper in several ways: increase visibility+citeability+journal acceptence of the paper. These are the things that the prof can surely help if I ask. Also, the prof can help with certain unsolved parts of the paper-- I can solve them somehow myself but he can solve it differently and maybe more elegantly (maybe not). I am wondering which is a better option for my future academia life.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=gift+authorship

The answer to the question in the title is "no, that's unethical".  Based on the body of the question, perhaps you really mean "is it a good idea to collaborate with a 'big name'".  If that's what you mean, I suggest revising the title.

A friend tried this in his first paper. Not only he is "et. al." now, but the big names didn't do anything or increased the citation numbers of the paper.

There are a couple of unclear writings. For example regarding your edit there is the "Also, [...] " which is awful, since you stated: "increase visibility+citeability+journal acceptence of the paper. These are the things that the prof can surely help if I ask"
False. You do not do this with "the help of big prof", you improve these aspects by "improving the unsolved part of the paper".
Whether the big prof is really the person that can help with the unsolved parts of the paper remains to be discussed, and it is worthwhile to ask before going to Berkeley, so you know if it is worthwhile.

"The problem with my previous papers is that although 2 of them so far were accepted to a journal, they have no citations so far".
How do you advertise them? do you present at conferences/workshop/peers? are you working on the same topic? Big professors publish so many papers that you probably do not realize that even they have papers that go not cited for months/years.

@DavidKetcheson there is no question in the title, what do you mean?

"they have no citations". If you work systematically, you could already have 6 self-citations and the Hirsch index of 2.

@FerventHippo The title has been edited.

@DavidKetcheson if so I propose further edits to the question title because it doesn't seem very useful for future searches on the topic.

If your paper contains some nice results and is essentially done, then I think you should submit it before you show up at Berkeley. Once there, show it to your big name prof and suggest working together on extensions and new ideas it suggests.
If it's not really finished and there are results you are close to that ought to be included, ask your big name prof to work with you to prove them.
Just pay attention to the mathematics.
Trying to game the system by massaging authorship is at best a waste of effort, at worst unethical.

"Trying to game the system by massaging authorship" big professor is smart enough to smell if OP is tricking them in the paper just for the name: it will be a rough and sad half a year visit starting on that premises...

@EarlGrey Indeed. The great name prof had been an ambitious youngster themselves and know their psychology, whether on themselves or their peers.

Unless they contribute to the paper, they cannot be co-authors.
But maybe they can contribute if they are so brilliant, and they can improve the paper.
What you should not do is to add them just to puff up the paper. If they have integrity, they will be insulted by the idea, and if they do not, do you really want to work with them?

@Fe2O3 I like the word "reverse nepotism", although I am not sure what it means, precisely. Does it mean "adopt an uncle" or "adopt a nephew"?

I agree with the other answers that a person should be an author only if they make a substantial contribution to the paper. But I have another point: "Big name prof" also knows this. If you ask him to be co-author without doing any real work, then he might start thinking less of you.
OTOH - you got accepted for a program at a really good university under (apparently) a really good professor. Congratulations! You are doing many things right.
So, submit this paper solo. See what happens. You will have plenty of time to submit papers with big name prof.

Let me give you a more pragmatic answer than all those saying that this is unethical. Yes, this is unethical, but pretty much the whole academic pipeline is tainted in one way or another. Those who think academia is a completely moral space are delusional. In the grand scheme of things, this is probably one of the least harmful ways to go around the established rules. However, I think this is a bad idea for other reasons:
One risk you may run into by adding them as a coauthor is that people won't know who came up with the ideas, writing, execution, etc. Unless this person clarifies it from the get go, many will think that the idea and main arguments were provided by them and you are just tagging along. In fact, I know of a couple of big names who would gladly take the credit in a situation like this.
A second concern is the Professor may take this badly over ethical concerns or some other reason. I wouldn't risk my reputation for something like this.
Instead, you should let your work speak for itself. I would make it a point to present my work to them and to the rest of the faculty in the area. Then, you can ask the Professor for insights on how to extend it, and perhaps, invite them to collaborate if they feel so inclined.

Yes, by all means try to be a co-author with Dr. Bigshot.
Just don't go and say that you have this paper already written up and you want to add him, because this would be prima facie unethical. Just invite him to co-author the paper with you, send him your paper with the word "draft" at the top, and he'll send it back with a few minor corrections, if any at all, and voilà, you've co-authored a paper with a big shot. This is how super stars in academia get 50 papers published a year.
One of the demigods in my field used to publish dozens of papers a year while living 215 miles away from campus and having a full-time job promoting his 22 popular-science books. I knew him and some of his close colleagues (some of them deities themselves), and I assure you that he performed 0% of the research written in those papers. This is just normal life in academia.
How beneficial this will be for your career is another matter, but that's another question.

Although "he'll send it back with a few minor corrections" is possible, it's also possible that he'll decide that he doesn't actually want to be a co-author.

@AndreasBlass Always a possibility. But worth the try.

This is absolutely not an appropriate way to game authorship. A few comments is not sufficient for authorship, this answer proposes a highly unethical approach. The people publishing this way are faking their way to productivity based on name recognition alone. This is the worst category of gift authorship. Gross.

In addition to the ethical problems: as a Mediumshot professor, if somebody wrote me out of the blue with a manuscript and said "I'd like you to be a co-author on this", my response would be "ummmmmm, no". I imagine true Bigshots are even more careful with where they allocate their energy.

Worthwhile to note that the author of the 50 paper published in a year says himself
"I do consider myself someone who publishes lots of papers. I think my peak is around 50 in a single year."

to be honest, this answer sounds very postironic where it is hard to determine if it is a joke or not and is at the edge of irony and seriousness but leaning towards irony

@Mihail I might tend to agree with you if not for the last sentence of the response. But maybe it's meta-meta.

@Mihail Yes, I was being ironic, thank you. But I am surprised how much I enjoyed the downvotes. Gift, honorary, and ghost authorship have absolutely ruined publishing in academia, and I am sick of it. How many papers you publish has come to mean nothing. Maybe the upside is that at one point we'll be forced to evaluate researchers based on the merits of their ideas and not publication count, grant money, and bigshot affiliation.

@Cheery Maybe you want to make it clearer that it is an "anti-advice"? These can be quite useful in reflecting to the OP how absurd their question is. I am taking back my downvote.

@Cheery I should add to your remarks - every ranking system can be gamed. It is therefore absurd to believe that it is possible to have an "algorithm" that will just churn out clear quality criteria and that takes the responsibility for decisions off the committee's shoulders. The reason search committees do that is that it is hard to judge good research. The best search committees understand and embrace this.
